# Show top 3 ranked values in a column tooltip

Tags: tooltip, powerbi, dax, rank

I want to make a tooltip that, when an item in a chart is hovered over, shows the top 3 names in a column that's ranked by the number of times they appear.

I found two pieces of code that each do half of the trick but have tried and failed to combine them.

**Code to find the most commonly occurring value:**

```
TopIssue = 
FIRSTNONBLANK (
    TOPN (
        1, 
        VALUES ( FlagReport[Cat 3] ), 
        RANKX( ALL( FlagReport[Cat 3] ), [IssueCount],,ASC)
    ), 
    1)
```

Where `IssueCount = COUNT(FlagReport[Ref No])`

This works fine, but when I change the 1 -> 2 -> 3 it doesn't correlate correctly with the ranking as when I change it to 2 it doesn't show the correct value

**Code to show the first 3 string values that occur:**

```
List of Cat 3 values = 
VAR __DISTINCT_VALUES_COUNT = DISTINCTCOUNT('FlagReport'[Cat 3])
VAR __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW = 3
RETURN
    IF(
        __DISTINCT_VALUES_COUNT > __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW,
        CONCATENATE(
            CONCATENATEX(
                TOPN(
                    __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW,
                    VALUES('FlagReport'[Cat 3]),
                    'FlagReport'[Cat 3],
                    ASC
                ),
                'FlagReport'[Cat 3],
                ", ",
                'FlagReport'[Cat 3],
                ASC
             ),
            ", etc."
        ),
        CONCATENATEX(
            VALUES('FlagReport'[Cat 3]),
            'FlagReport'[Cat 3],
            ", ",
            'FlagReport'[Cat 3],
            ASC
        )
    )
```

This code shows me the first 3 string values but doesn't let me rank them.

I have been trying and failing with this for far too long considering it sounds like a theoretically simple thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making it a bit more complex than it needs to be. The first code gets you most of the way there. You just need to wrap it in a concatenate function and make sure you have the ordering set correctly.

```
Top3 = CONCATENATEX(
          TOPN(3, 
              VALUES(FlagReport[Cat 3]),
              RANKX(ALL(FlagReport[Cat 3]), [IssueCount], ,ASC)),
          FlagReport[Cat 3], ", ", [IssueCount], DESC)
```

The `TOPN` function finds the top 3 ranked items. Then we concatenate the `Cat 3` column using `[IssueCount]` as the order by expression.

Comment: I clearly was over complicating it and this works perfectly!

I had tried similar but this bit seemed to be where I was going wrong:

FlagReport[Cat 3], ", ", [IssueCount],  - I am assuming that the ,"," essentially states do the same as before  but will study the code more to make sure I completely understand it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `", "` is the delimiter. It says to put a comma and space between the items you're concatenating together.